# Creating an HTML 5 audio player

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm trying to build an html5/javascript mp3 player on my webpage but the site is playing no sound. I have the song in the root directory with my index.html file. Why is it when I hit play on the mp3 file, it doesn't play?

Heres my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" media="screen" />
    <link href="menu_source/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="music.js"></script>
    <script>
        var player;
        var intv;
        var slider;

        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('btnPlay').addEventListener('click', playMusic, false);
            document.getElementById('btnPause').addEventListener('click', btnPause, false);
            document.getElementById('btnStop').addEventListener('click', btnStop, false);
            document.getElementById('btnVolUp').addEventListener('click', , false);
            document.getElementById('btnVolDown').addEventListener('click', volDown, false);
            player = document.getElementById('player');
            slider = document.getElementById('sliderTime');
            slider.addEventListener('change', reposition, false);
            getMusicList();
        }

        function reposition() {
            player.currentTime = slider.value;
        }

         //Volume Controls
        function volUp() {
            if (player.volume < 1) {
                player.volume += 0.1;
                console.log(player.volume);
            } else {
                player.volume = 1;
            }
        }

        function volDown() {
            if (player.volume > 0) {
                player.volume -= 0.1;
                console.log(player.volume);
            } else {
                player.volume = 0;
            }
        }
         //MUSIC PLAY CONTROLS

        function playMusic() {
            player.play();
            intv = setInterval(update, 100);
            slider.max = player.duration;
        }

        function update() {
            document.getElementById('songTime').innerHTML = millisToMins(player.currentTime);
            slider.value = player.currentTime;
        }

        function millisToMins(seconds) {
            var numminutes = Math.floor((((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
            var numseconds = (((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) % 60;
            if (numseconds >= 10) {
                return "Time Elapsed: " + numminutes + ":" + Math.round(numseconds);
            } else {
                return "Time Elapsed:" + numminutes + ":0: + Math.round(numseconds);
}
}
function pauseMusic(){
player.pause();
clearInterval(intv);l

}
function stopMusic(){
    player.pause();
    player.currentTime = 0;
    clearInterval(intv);
}
function getMusicList(){
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDocument = parser.parseFromString(xml, "
                text / xml ");
    var elementsArray = xmlDocument.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('composition');
    var arrayLength = elementsArray.length;
    var output = " < table > ";
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength, i++){
        var title = elementsArray[i].getElementsByTagName('title'[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var composer = elementsArray[i].getElementsByTagName('composer')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var time = elementsArray[i].getElementsByTagName('time')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var fileName = elementsArray[i].getElementsByTagName('filename')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        output += " < tr > ";
        output += (" < td onclick = 'songSelect(\"" + fileName + "\")' > " + title + "
                By: " + composer + " < /td>");
        output += "</table > ";
        document.getElementById('musicList').innerHTML = output;
}
function songSelect(fn){
    //console.log(fn);
    document.getElementById('player').src = fn;
    playMusic();
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="logo2">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div ng-controller="logOut">
                        <div id="logOut1">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="singleModel" btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="1" btn-checkbox-false="0">
                                Logout
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>
                angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
            </script>
            <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
            <div id="content2">
                <div id="audioPlayer">
                    <audio id="player">
                        <source src="SleepAway.mp3" />
                        <source src="SleepAway.ogg" />
                    </audio>
                    <button id="btnPlay">Play</button>
                    <button id="btnPause">Pause</button>
                    <button id="btnStop">Stop</button>
                    <button id="btnVolUp">Volume Up</button>
                    <button id="btnVolDown">Volume Down</button>
                    <span id="songTime"></span>
                    <br/>
                    <input id="sliderTime" type="range" min="0" value="0" />
                    <div id="musicList"></div>
                </div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var audio = document.getElementById("player"),
        play = document.getElementById("play"),
        timer = document.getElementById("timer"),
        update;

    audio.addEventListener("click, PlayAudio, false);
          play.addEventListener("
        click, PlayAudio, false);

     //play or pause audio
    functon PlayAudio(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (audio.paused) {
            audio.play();
            play.textContent = "Pause";
        } else {
            audio.pause();
            play.textContent = "Play";
        }
    }
    document.write("Hello World!");
</script>
```

Comment: Usually you will have a better chance to get the answers you're looking for, and get them faster, by making your code short and to the point. Try removing any code that isn't directly involved in the part where your problem occurs, or try making a simplified analogous code that exhibits the same problem for you.

Comment: This is a hacked down version of my site. I removed everything but the components to an html5 player I'm trying to build, but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @joeytje50 is right, there's far too much code here. Have you checked the console for errors? I can see two syntax errors in your main.js.

Comment: Why don't use just use the built in `<video>` and `<audio>` players that work out of the box? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Comment: I hope that code you pasted as "main.js" code is not actually saved with the `<script>` tags around it... If you save a file as `.js` file, you don't need, infact, you shouldn't add the script tags around it. It'll cause errors.

Comment: I made some corrections and I still have a problem playing the file. Please advise is you can. Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/D894sZrL

Comment: Look at your console for errors. You're missing quotes around the event names in the event listeners you add in main.js

Comment: I fixed the missing quotes but it still doesnt play the mp3 file. updated code: http://pastebin.com/gKP7BXUE

Answer (score 0):

```
var player = document.createElement('audio');
player.src = 'your_source_here.mp3';
player.controls = true;
document.body.appendChild(player);
```